# How to make a Latex table span multiple pages and how to write notes under the caption of this long table?

Tags: tables

How do you make a Latex table span multiple pages? In particular, is it possible to divide up a table such that the second part of the table is in a new page and not numbered (i.e., labeled as Table Continued). I have the following table and want to transfer Panel c to the next page, in such a way that it is not numbered and that it is titled Table, Continued. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,notitlepage]{article}

\begin{document}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex,booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{center}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{}
\label{tab:table4}
\justifying
\begin{tablenotes}
\justify
Text
\end{tablenotes}
\par
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\midrule 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{PANEL A} & & \\ 
X & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} \\ 
X & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} \\ 
X & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} \\ 
X & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} \\ 
X & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{X} & & \\ 
\midrule 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{PANEL B} & & \\ 
X & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} \\ 
X & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} \\ 
X & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} \\ 
X & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} \\ 
X & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} \\ 
X & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} \\ 
X & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} \\ 
\midrule 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{PANEL C} & & \\ 
X & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} \\ 
X & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} \\ 
X & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} \\ 
X & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} \\ 
X & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} \\ 
X & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} \\ 
\midrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{table}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

You *can* add tablenotes with `longtable` if you load the `threeparttablex` package, which is done for that. Its use is slightly different from `threparttable`. The main difference is that you *begin* with defining what' in your notes, then ask to insert them at the place you want. So the general structure would be this:

```
\begin{ThreePartTable}
   \begin{TableNotes}
       ⁝
   \end{TableNotes}
   \begin{longtable}
     \caption{mycaption}\label{mylabel}\\
       ⁝
     \endfirsthead
       ⁝
     \endhead
       ⁝
     \endfoot
     \insertTableNotes
     \endlastfoot
       ⁝
       ⁝
       ⁝
   \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
```

Further, the `ltablex` package brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`. You also can use it with `threeparttablex`. The only difference with the previous scheme is you'll have to replace `longtable` with `tabularx`, and add the specification `\keepXColumns`, otherwise the calculated width of `X` columns will only be their maximum width,their real width depending on their contents.

Last detail: there's no point loading `tabularx` nor `longtable` if you  use `ltablex`, since they're required by this package.

Comment: Bernard, how do I break the page when I want with longtable? Also, could you give me a quick example to switch from longtable to ltablex? ( I've tried switching but still not there -- the table does not break but continues through the table)

Comment: Breaking page with `longtable` can be done with `\pagebreak` or `\newpage` *at the beginning of a row* (not sure works with `ltablex`. Switching from `longtable`  to `ltablex` just consists in replacing the `longtable` environment with `tabularx{width}`. If it doesn't work, you should post a minimal (non-)working example.